# How to show the QueryString received by an AJAX HTTP Request

Tags: asp-classic, xmlhttprequest, query-string, jscript, server-variables

We have a script A which pulls information by sending an HTTPRequest to script B, with some GET parameters.

```
var URL = "http://domain.com/scriptB?ID="+ID;
var XMLGateway = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
    XMLGateway.open("GET", URL, false);
    XMLGateway.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

This script B then uses an ID in the querystring passed to it to return some information. However this is inconsistently throwing errors.

Some investigation shows instead of the ID we're passing in the GET (which always takes the format of a five digit number), it is using a string like ".sp-app-5" where the number has been 5-9 so far.

```
String("["+Request("ID")+"]"); // [.sp-app-9]
```

I'm having trouble dealing with this bug as Request.QueryString used in script B is showing the QS that script A receives. However, Request("ID") is returning the unusual string as above.

```
Server.HTMLEncode(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")); // domain.com
Server.HTMLEncode(Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")); // scriptA?some=values&foo=bar (same result as Request.QueryString)
```

How can I show the querystring that script B is receiving in the HTTP Request?

Comment: Couldn't you just fire `http://domain.com/scriptB.asp?ID=12345` in a browser and see what it returns, wouldn't that tell you if the script is screwing up the `ID` value being passed?

Comment: Going directly to it works as expected. And it returns the QS correctly in that case too. But obviously that's no good for tracking down this bug as I'm not able to recreate the circumstances that cause it.

I'm quite confident it's nothing on script B fudging the QS

Comment: And you're confident that `ID` being passed on `scriptA.asp` into `WinHttpRequest` is correct?

Comment: Yes. The script that it's running through would be egregiously more broken were the ID's coming in incorrectly. To get to the point it's at the ID has been used earlier in the flow. Sorry I can't use the production code but I tried to boil the problem down as much as possible.

Comment: Still trying to get my head around this statement - *"I'm having trouble dealing with this bug as Request.QueryString used in script B is showing the QS that script A receives. However, Request("ID") is returning the unusual string as above."* Did you mean that `Response.Write Request.QueryString` in `scriptB.asp` will show the querystring passed into `scriptA.asp` instead of the expected `ID=12345`?

Comment: The problem with *"boiling it down"* is you're likely to remove a key line which would explain what is happening, have you tried placing `Response.Write "ID is " + ID;` before the `var URL` line in the above code to double check the `ID` isn't changing?

Comment: The comment above is correct. If I run ScriptA with a given QS, when I print out the QS inside ScriptB, it returns that rather than the one being used in the HTTP Request. HOWEVER, when I specifically request ID, it returns the unusual string, despite ID not even being a part of the original QS being used to run ScriptA. Have also checked ID isn't changing in the script anywhere. No indication that it is doing so.

Comment: That is very strange and I don't think the *"boiled down"* code is going to be enough to help diagnose the problem. It's almost like there is a `Server.Transfer` happening instead of the `WinHttpRequest` being processed separately.

Comment: There is a Server.Transfer done earlier on in the flow (ScriptA and B are only part of a longer path). Will keep experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to verify that Script A is sending the GET Querystring in the request correctly. For situations like this I often use a free tool called "Fiddler" from Telerek (on windows). It will watch all your http calls and log the request and response, including the query string. Its pretty easy to install and is very useful when doing this type of project.

This will help you narrow down if script A is sending the ID correctly, or if Script B is interpreting the ID incorrectly.

Hope this helps!

[image: Example of fiddler output]

[www.telerik.com/download/fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler)

Comment: I've briefly played with this tool before. I'll have to check that we can run this safely on one of our machines though. Logging all traffic would be too big a load.

Comment: I typically run it on my development laptop where I'd be making a "SCRIPT A" call. That way you only log your development laptop calls.